# Strict inequality in spectral radius estimate

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

I am interested to find an example which shows strict inequality in the spectral radius estimate that is $r(x) \leq \|x \|$ . I would like to see when $r(x) < \|x\|$.Normal operator is the case where equality holds. Trying to find where the strict inequality hold.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Take any non-zero nilpotent operator. For instance, $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

Answer (score 0):

[Prahlad Vaidyanathan](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/590404/strict-inequality-in-spectral-radius-estimate#comment1245855_590404) gave a simple example 
$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
to which I'll add an example with $0<r(x)<\|x\|$:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1/2\end{pmatrix}$$